# LiipImagineBundle - dynamic filter parameters

Tags: symfony, twig, liipimaginebundle

With LiipImagineBundle is it possible to use a filter in twig like this?

```
<img src="{{ url|imagine_filter('thumbnail', '200', '100') }}" />
```

It should generate an image based on `thumbnail` filter:

```
liip_imagine:
    filter_sets:
        cache: ~
        thumbnail:
            quality: 90
            filters:
                thumbnail: { size: [XXX, YYY], mode: outbound }
```

where `XXX` and `YYY` are the filter parameters (width and height).

The solution does now have to be exactly the same, but it's important for me to be able to prepare a simple filters 'on the fly' without having to declare all of them in the config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can change options on the fly using runtimeConfig

```
{% set runtimeConfig = {"thumbnail": {"size": [50, 50] }} %}
<img src="{{ url | imagine_filter('my_filter_from_config_yml', runtimeConfig) }}" />
```

Comment: Great, that's exactly what I was looking for :)